# Facebook Pop Unresolved Identifier Issues

Tags: c++, cocoapods, swift2, xcode7, facebook-pop

I am migrating my iOS project from XCode 6.4 to XCode 7.  Also migrating the code from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0.  The project uses several cocoapods and all of them are working great EXCEPT Pop, which also happens to be the only one written in C++.  For this line of code:

```
let anim = POPSpringAnimation(propertyNamed: kPOPViewScaleXY)
```

I am getting build failures:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'POPSpringAnimation'
Use of unresolved identifier 'kPOPViewScaleXY'
```

My bridging header has:

```
#import <pop/POP.h>
```

I have also tried  and still get the same problem.  My folder is actually "pop".

I have tried adding the path to my header search paths explicitly, in a few different forms, both the Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths, but still get the same errors.

My latest `pod update` says: Using pop (1.0.8)
...which is the latest, and I even tried the "bleeding edge" option and I still get version 1.0.8.

Anyone else seeing this, or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.  All I had to do was put this at the top of my Swift 2.0 source file:

```
import pop
```

It appears that was not required until we ported to XCode 7 / Swift 2.0.